# python: Find subsets coordinate is in

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I have a set of coordinates and try to find those subsets the coordinate is in.

```
import numpy as np
a=np.array([[[0,1,1],[1,1,1]],[[0,1,1],[2,1,1]],[[3,3,3],[2,2,2]]])
```

If I try things like:

```
print(np.argwhere(a==[[0,1,1]]))
print(a[[0,1,1]])
print(np.isin([0,1,1],a))
```

I get:

```
[[0 0 0]
 [0 0 1]
 [0 0 2]
 [0 1 1]
 [0 1 2]
 [1 0 0]
 [1 0 1]
 [1 0 2]
 [1 1 1]
 [1 1 2]]
[[[0 1 1]
  [1 1 1]]

 [[0 1 1]
  [2 1 1]]

 [[0 1 1]
  [2 1 1]]]
[ True  True  True]
```

But I expect something like:

```
[true,true,false]
```

**EDIT**

The best case would be If I get an array where only all other coordinates which are members of the founded subsets are in like:

```
out = [[1,1,1],[2,1,1]]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `all(-1)` to assert the array equal at the last axis and then `any(1)` to check if such condition exists at the second axis:

```
(a == [0,1,1]).all(-1).any(1)
# array([ True,  True, False], dtype=bool)
```

---

*On the update*:

```
mask = (a == [0,1,1]).all(-1)
a[mask.any(1)[:,None] & ~mask]

#array([[1, 1, 1],
#       [2, 1, 1]])
```

Comment: Nice answer, thank you! :) Is there also a possibility to excluce the coordinate which i used fr the search and to write all othere founded coordinates in only one array?

Answer (score 0):

I got the results you're looking for by doing this:

```
[[0,1,1] in b for b in a]
```

I'll try to figure out why `isin` didnt work.